# Sending Base 64 string as request parameter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, base64

I have the following scenario where the user will upload an image and then I take the base 64 string of that image to pass it in a fancybox src as a URL parameter

The problem is the URL is too long (error 414) and I don't know how should I fix this issue

here is my code

```
<a class="list-link" href="javascript:;" onclick="GenerateMapCode(this);" data-img="previewFloorImage" data-src="@Url.Content("~/js/mapeditor/index.htm")">Generate code</a>

<input accept="image/*" id="FloorImage" name="FloorImage" target="previewFloorImage" type="file" />
<img id="previewImage" width="100%" style="display:block; margin-top:15px" alt="" />

<script>
function GenerateMapCode(sender) {
var imgid = $(sender).data("img");
var imgsrc = $("#" + imgid).attr("src");
if (imgsrc === null || imgsrc === undefined) {
    alert("no image selected");
    return;
}

var url = $(sender).data("src") + "?src=" + imgsrc;
$.fancybox.open({
    padding: 0,
    src: url,
    type: 'iframe'
});

}
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of parameters you may want to send it as JSON body.

Comment: how that? should be done?

Comment: @Sora Server side, depending on how is your server side implemented

Comment: you mean to send it as ajax, but I don't want to use any server side code

Answer (score 0):

You could use the FileReader API to read the file's data URL from the input like this.

```js
const floorImage = document.getElementById('FloorImage');
const previewImage = document.getElementById('previewImage');

floorImage.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const fr = new FileReader();
  
  fr.addEventListener('load', (frEvent) => {
    previewImage.src = frEvent.target.result;
  });
  fr.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
});

function GenerateMapCode(sender) {
var imgid = $(sender).data("img");
var imgsrc = $("#" + imgid).attr("src");
if (imgsrc === null || imgsrc === undefined) {
    alert("no image selected");
    return;
}

var url = $(sender).data("src") + "?src=" + imgsrc;
console.log(url);
/*
$.fancybox.open({
    padding: 0,
    src: url,
    type: 'iframe'
});
*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="list-link" href="javascript:;" onclick="GenerateMapCode(this);" data-img="previewImage" data-src="@Url.Content("~/js/mapeditor/index.htm")">Generate code</a>

<input accept="image/*" id="FloorImage" name="FloorImage" target="previewImage" type="file" />
<img id="previewImage" width="100%" style="display:block; margin-top:15px" alt="" />
```

Comment: i am already doing this, but this is not my problem, i want to send the base64 image to fancybox ifram